filter hook yith_wcan_terms_on_first_loading
This yith_wcan_terms_on_first_loading filter hook is defined in the free yith plugin in the WordPress repository.
How to connect to this hook and change the value?
I am trying to change the value using the following code:
add_filter( 'yith_wcan_terms_on_first_loading', function( $number ) {

    $number = 20;
    return $number;

}, 10, 1 );

I also executed this code in the init and plugins_loaded action hook, but it still didn't work.
Please advise.
Unfortunately, there is no documentation for customizing this plugin. Dear friends and experts, please take this issue seriously and if you have any idea or opinion, let us know so that we can reach a conclusion.
Regards
Sajad
